# How to create simple UI text after deleting TextMeshPro in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, text

I just deleted the TextMeshPro package and I don't know where to create a simple UI text now.

It doesn't show it for me anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about `TextMeshPro`?

Usually if you right click in the **hierarchy**, you will find stuff as text elements under `UI`. If you have `TextMeshPro` installed you still can find regular `Button`, `Text`, `Input` etc. elements under `UI` > `Legacy`.

Comment: Thanks I just downloaded a new version of unity editor and now I see that now they are at the legacy